# Angular Flex: The height of mat-dialog-content is not correct when using fxLayoutGap with grid option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

When I create a modal window with a content to be displayed with fxLayoutGap and the grid option, the height of the content area of the dialog is not calculated correctly. Instead of enlarging the dialog box, an overflow occurs.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-jror5h

**Code of the Modal Component:**

```
  <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
      <div fxFlex="33.3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 1</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 1" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="66.7">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 2</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 2" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="33.3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 3</mat-label>
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option [value]="true">yes</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="false">no</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="33.3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 4</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 4" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="33.3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 4</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 4" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="50">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 100%">
          <mat-label>FormControl 5</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 5" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="50">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>FormControl 6</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="FormControl 4" type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
```

**The rendered Modal Component:**
[image: Rendered Modal Component]
How can the problem be solved without specifying a fixed height for mat-dialog-content?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I specified a fixed height as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your `component.ts` file and then in the `component.css` file add
`.mat-dialog-content { overflow: hidden; }`

I noticed you were using `::ng-deep`, which is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

[This is the forked stackblitz showing it works.](https://angular-material-farsat.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Use **fxFlexFill** directive for correct height

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem with the overflow.  Try it out with the StackBlitz :).

Answer (score -1):

you can set height of your modal before opening it from dialog configuration:

```
openModal() {
    this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      height: '400px'
    });
  }
```

You include **mat-dialog-content** inside **form**, this is wrong.

mat-dialog-content is parent for your modal content and mat-dialog-actions can be used as a footer for this

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem with the overflow. I want the dialog box to grow dynamically up to the maximum possible height of 65vh, before a scroll bar for the content appears.

Comment: If you were to put the fixed width, the questioner wouldn't use fxLayout